# How to decribe all bounded Borel functions where Lebesgue integral is zero

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-measures

I'm working on an exercise and I'm not quite sure how to answer it. I need to describe all bounded borel measurable functions $f: [0,1] \to [-1,1]$ where
$$ \int_{[a,b)} f d\lambda = 0  $$
There is a hint: decomposition $f=f_+ + f_-$ . Here I'm thinking that this means that $f_+ = f_-$ , but I dont know if this is allowed in this setting. 
My question is how do I solve an exercise like this?

Comment: You have the right idea. What other functions might behave in this way besides functions with equal 'area' above and below?

Comment: I can only think of the function which is zero everywhere

Comment: Hint: what is the integral of $f^+,\ f^-$ on sets of measure zero?

Comment: @Vics, what about the function which is zero everywhere but at exactly $3$ points? What would the Lebesgue integral of this be?

Comment: Oh, yes, the integral over null set is zero.  For the function of zero everywhere but 3 points, I would also say zero, but I am new measure theory so don't know how to argue this point. It is just my intuition and remembering studying the measure of the Cantor set.

Comment: Good intuition. $3$ discrete points have a set of measure zero...